# random number generator, number guess. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python

I have this basic code and what I want it to do is choose a random number, then it would ask the user to input a number from 0 to 100, the would give back results based on the number, such as number is too low or high. I keep switching things around but always get an error, this for 2.7:

```
import random
randomNumber = random.randrange(0,100)
guess = -1
guess = int(input('Enter a number between 0 and 100: ')
guess != randomNumber:
if guess < randomNumber
    print('Your guess is too low.')
elif guess > randomNumber:
    print('Your guess is too high.')
print('You win!')
```

Comment: What error are you always getting? Indentation error?

Comment: (and extra colon on `!=` line - but what was it meant to do?)

Comment: Also missing a closing parentheses `...and 100: '))`

Comment: You should use python3.x

Comment: @Ren Using Python2.7 is fine and is what the OP stated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: @Alexander Python3 was released 7 years ago. There's no excuse for anyone new to the language to be using Python2 anymore (but frankly this is all off-topic to this off-topic question)

Comment: @AdamSmith while I partially agree, that's a very bold statement. People have reasons, if the need for 2.7 isn't there, then why a release was sent out in December. I'm sure it'll stop as time moves on, but anyone should be free to use whatever version they're comfortable with.

Comment: @Leb Anyone new to the language isn't comfortable with any version by definition. Lots of 3rd-party packages haven't been updated to Python3 for some inexplicable reason in the intervening most-of-a-decade, so if you're forced to use Py2.7 for legacy purposes that's one thing. OP is fairly clearly learning the language. There's no reason I can imagine that they shouldn't be learning Py3. It's a waste of time.

Comment: The fact that I'm choosing to use python2 shouldn't be a problem, if you're not trying to help theres no need for you to comment. But I took all the suggestions and figured out what was wrong, thanks to those who helped

Comment: @Fettucini glad you solved it. Next time please post your complete stack trace with any code that's throwing an error. This question is off-topic because it does not contain the error you got. If a particular answer helped you arrive at a solution you can tick the green checkmark to mark it as accepted. If you derived an answer independently you can self-answer (I think even at 1 rep) and check that as accepted after a day or two.

Comment: See edited answer if you want your code to keep asking you for input until you guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you define `guess` twice. Just define it once. There is no need to make `guess` be equal to -1 if that won't be the original value anyways. Second, I believe you want to use a `while` loop to keep checking if the user has guessed the correct number. In this case, add another `guess` into the `while` loop to allow the player to continue guessing and to keep proper syntax.

Don't let the player win always with another condition. Use colons after each `if/elif` statement as well. As you are comparing a string (the input) and an integer, change the `input()` to `int(input())`. The final code should be something like:

```
import random

randomNumber = random.randrange(0, 100)
guess = None                                   # Define guess

while guess != randomNumber:                   # Create loop 
    guess = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 100"))   # Change guess
    if guess < randomNumber:
        print "Your guess is too low."
    elif guess > randomNumber:
        print "Your guess is too high."
    elif guess == randomNumber:
        print "You win!"                        # Win message under correct condition
        break                                   # Exit the loop as game is finished
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a colon after your if statement. You're also printing `You win!` regardless of the outcome. Put that inside an `else` statement. You don't need this line `guess != randomNumber:`, and you don't need `guess=-1`, and finally you're missing a closing paren as mentioned in comments.

```
import random
randomNumber = random.randrange(0,100)
guess = None
while guess != randomNumber:
    guess = int(input('Enter a number between 0 and 100: '))
    if guess == randomNumber:
        break
    elif guess < randomNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > randomNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
print('You win!')
```

Comment: That's not nearly all.

Comment: whoops, you're right I missed a whole guess!= and a missing paren

Comment: You still always stay in the loop as you never break outside the loop. Use another condition in which when met, uses `break` to exit the loop

Comment: whoops again, thanks @PythonMaster

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT - removed some unecessary lines)

missing some formatting, and there's a few lines (guess != randomNumber:) that don't really do anything (and in that case, the colon would cause a SyntaxError).

```
import random

randomNumber = random.randrange(0,100)

guess = int(input('Enter a number between 0 and 100: '))

if guess < randomNumber:
    print('Your guess is too low.')
elif guess > randomNumber:
    print('Your guess is too high.')
else: # assuming you only want to print this if they guessed right
    print('You win!')
```

Comment: This gives me a syntax error on the colon on line 6

Comment: Try it now - made some additional changes

Comment: Works perfectly, just one thing though it doesn't keep looping until I get it right, just takes one value and tells me if its too high or low and stops. How would I get it to keep going through until I get the correct number

Answer (score 0):

As usual, commenting your code reveals the error instantly

```
import random

# Pick a number between 0 and 99
randomNumber = random.randrange(0,100)

# initialize guess  (hint: why?)
guess = -1

# Ask the user to guess a number  (hint: balanced parentheses help)
guess = int(input('Enter a number between 0 and 100: ')

# What is this line supposed to be? Looks like the beginning of a loop here, but what kind?
guess != randomNumber:
# If the guess is less than the number, then tell the user
if guess < randomNumber
    print('Your guess is too low.')
# Otherwise if the guess is higher than the number, tell the user
elif guess > randomNumber:
    print('Your guess is too high.')

# Regardless, win the game. Wait whuh..?
print('You win!')
```

Comment: You gotta tell the OP how to fix the code to...

Comment: @PythonMaster why?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import random
randomNumber = random.randrange(0,100)
guess = int(input("Enter a number between 0 and 100:"))
if guess < randomNumber:
    print('Your guess is too low.')
elif guess > randomNumber:
    print('Your guess is too high.')
else:
    print('You win!')
```